# Como tornar o reCAPTCHA do google obrigatório "required"

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Bom, implementei o google reCAPTCHA nos formulários do meu site, funcionando normal, porém é possível enviar os formulários sem selecionar o captcha, como faço para ele ser um campo obrigatório antes do submit como um "required" ?

Comment: Você colocou o reCAPTCHA dentro da tag <form> ? acredito que essa adição ao site ja o torna obrigatório.

Comment: Sim está dentro do <form> , será que poderia ser porque estou testando em um servidor local?

Comment: Muito provavelmente pode ser isso, você ja deu uma olhada na documentação ?, de uma testada na resposta também acho que pode funcionar, mas lembrando que utilizo reCAPTCHA nos meus sites e nunca precisei validar manualmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu achei isso é acredito ser a maneira mais rápida para implementar, adicione esse codigo ao seu header

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var recaptcha = document.forms["Seu-Form"]["g-recaptcha-response"];
    recaptcha.required = true;
    recaptcha.oninvalid = function(e) {
    // fazer algo, no caso to dando um alert
    alert("Por favor complete o captchaba");
      }
   }
   </script>
```

Obs: Isso funciona apenas com Html5, é uma solução rápida para seu problema.

Comment: No lugar do "Seu-Form", colocaria uma id do meu form?

Comment: Isso, qualquer problema chama nos comentários que resolvemos.

Comment: Se você puder enviar o form ou parte dele fica melhor ..

Comment: Consegui, estava errando uma coisa aqui, fiz do jeito que você colocou muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Use reCaptcha callback with jquery.validate

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#form").validate();
  $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", ($("#Form1").valid() ? false : "disabled"));
 });
  
    function recaptchaCallback(response) {
  $("#hidden-grecaptcha").val(response);
  $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", ($("#Form1").valid() ? false : "disabled"));
 };

 function recaptchaExpired() {
  $("#hidden-grecaptcha").val("");
  $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", ($("#Form1").valid() ? false : "disabled"));
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    
<form id="Form1" method="post" action="">
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xx-x" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="recaptchaExpired"></div>
 <input type="text" id="hidden-grecaptcha" name="hidden-grecaptcha" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px;" />
 <br />
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```